# ASP.NET Core MVC runtime exception: "PrecompiledViews" not found

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I've created a new empty ASP.NET Core web app (target framework is .NETCoreApp 1.1) in Visual Studio 2017. After adding the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 1.1.3 package I've got a runtime exception

```
{System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load the specified file.
File name: '%my-project-name%.PrecompiledViews'
  at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.ResolveUsingEvent(AssemblyName assemblyName)}
```

I've tried to create a new ASP.NET Core web app with demo controller/views but got the same issue. Downgrading to previous versions of Microsoft.AspNetCore.MVC package (1.1.1, 1.1.2) doesn't help too.

Does anyone encountered a similar problem? If so can you tell a solution?

**Update:** I've just enabled the "Enable Just My Code" option in VS Options => Debugging and this runtime exception is gone. But I'm still going for seeing variants of a solvation. Because of my solvation is looking like a workaround.

**Update:** Clearing of NuGet cache gives nothing too.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it is an only answer. "I've just enabled the "Enable Just My Code" option in VS Options => Debugging and this runtime exception is gone. But I'm still going for seeing variants of a solvation. Because of my solvation is looking like a workaround."